# Form dentro de um Form html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Uma dúvida que talvez possa ser simples, mas não tive escolha:

Tenho um FORM html principal, que capta todos os dados de uma table, o problema é que existe o upload de imagens dentro desse form, e esse upload é instantâneo sem o submit do form (feito com AJAX jquery), ou seja, é necessário um outro form para chamar o arquivo php que trata a imagem, o problema é que fica um form dentro do form, e os forms não se aninham, não funciona o form maior (a img é carregada mas o form maior não gera o submit),

alguém tem alguma ideia ou sugestão?

ps: não postei código pois não vejo necessidade, é um form dentro de outro e o form pai não funciona.

Comment: posta o código aí :)

Comment: Já tentou usar algo como $("#formPai").submit(); ? Não consegue enviar os dados via ajax sem precisar de outro form (pai)?

Comment: _"é necessário um outro form para chamar o arquivo php que trata a imagem"_ - porque não fazes isso com ajax também?

Comment: @Onaiggac, tentei sim, ele envia apenas até onde finalizada a chave do primeiro FORM, isso no chrome, outros navegadores ele não envia nada

Comment: @Sergio, O form que chama o php é em AJAX, é necessário o uso do form para este.

Comment: Eu estou pensando em criar com javascript algo para copiar os inputs do primeiro form para um input hidden no segundo form.

Comment: Essa ultima frase _"O form que chama o php é em AJAX, é necessário o uso do form para este"_ não é muito clara... podes explicar melhor? Precisas de enviar a imagem para o PHP antes de fazer submit da form certo? e depois receber e voltar a colocar na form?

Comment: Não consegue enviar o form pai via ajax? Se conseguir, tente colocar um identificador nos inputs e depois  (quando o botão de submit for clicado) vc captura os valores e envia via ajax.

Comment: @Onaiggac, foi isso que eu fiz!! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só para ter uma resposta. Segue o código HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input-form" name="input_pai_0" value="FormPai">
  <form>
      <input type="text" class="input-form" name="input_filho_0" value="FormFilho">
  </form>
  <button class="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Segue o js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnEnviar").click(function(){
        //Validações

        var dados = {};
        $(".input-form").each(function(){
            dados[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        });

        console.log(dados);

        $.post('/echo/json/', dados, function(data){
            alert('Dados enviados com sucesso!');
        });
    });
});
```

E link do exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/afkkobpd/