# Form dentro de Form

Tags: php, html

Bom dia!

Já verifiquei o link, [Form dentro de Form](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/form-dentro-de-um-form-html), mas não é isso que procuro.

Estou precisando saber se um form dentro do outro com dois botões e dois actions distintos funciona.

Exemplo:

```
<form type="post" action="dados_cadastrais.php">

    <form type="post" action="negocicao.php">
         <input type="text" value="nome" />
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <input type="text" value="Parcela">
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
</form>
```

Código real do projeto:

```
               <form method="post" action="<?= base_url()?>admin/credores/adicionar" id="form_credor_adicionar">
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom: 0px;"> <!--padding 0px -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
                                <input type="text" id="cnpj" name="cnpj" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="000.000.000-00" value="<?php echo set_value('cnpj'); ?>" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                                <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="firstname form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="maiuscula('.firstname')" placeholder="Informe o nome do devedor" value="<?php echo set_value('nome'); ?>" >                             
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                <label for="genero" class="control-label">Ativo</label>
                                <select id="genero" name="genero" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
                                    <option value="1">Sim</option>
                                    <option value="0">Não</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"> <!--margem 0px -->
                                <div class="card card-border nav-tabs-custom">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#dados_cadastrais" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color: #A4BE40"></i> Dados Cadastrais</a></li>
                                        <li class=""><a href="#tabela_negociacao" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" ><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color: #E9573F"></i> Tabela de Negociação</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="tab-content" style="">
                                        <?php include 'include/tab_adicionar_dados_cadastrais.php';?>
                                        <?php include 'include/tab_adicionar_tabela_negociacao.php';?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">                         
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat pull-left"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" onclick="limpar_campos(this.form)"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Limpar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>                           
                    </div>
                </form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual a necessidade disso?

Comment: Eu tenho um modal que contem dois tabs,
Onde o primeiro tab deve enviar dados cadastrais.
E o segundo tab, envia dados de negociação.

Ambos os tabs chamam controllers diferentes e enviam dados para tabelas direrentes.

Sendo que os dois tabs são chamados via include e estão entre um form.

Comment: Ainda nao entendi a necessidade de um form dentro do outro

Comment: Não funciona, só vai funcionar < input type="submit" value="Enviar" > no action dados_cadastrais.php

Comment: Veja a atualização do código.
<?php include 'include/tab_adicionar_tabela_negociacao.php';?>, nesta parte é um outro formulário

Comment: Não, não funciona. Elementos `form` não podem ser aninhados. Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200959/5878). Se os formulários utilizam controladores diferentes e enviam para tabelas diferentes, não faz sentido eles estarem no mesmo formulário.

Comment: Não mudou nada, veja vc mesmo  em http://kithomepage.com/sos/dois-forms.htm  só funciona o botão do form incluido com o action do primeiro form

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, assim que eu separar os dois form, a pagina fugira do layout, existe alguma outra forma de faze-lo ?

Comment: Sim, ajuste seu layout de acordo. Usar um formulário dentro de outro será gambiarra. Não faça isso.

Comment: Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Para não fugir do layout, vai ter que trabalhar um pouco. Coloque o segundo form dentro de uma div e fora do primeiro form. Com css vc é capaz de posicionar exatamente no local desejado. Fiz uma maquete, :) , veja em http://kithomepage.com/sos/dois-forms.htm tanto o "salvar"como o "enviar" funcionam.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, eu até coloquei um exemplo de imagens, pra voce ver como estou fazendo!
Neste linha: <div class="tab-content" style="">
                                        <?php include 'include/tab_adicionar_dados_cadastrais.php';?>
                                        <?php include 'include/tab_adicionar_tabela_negociacao.php';?>
                                    </div>
sobre tab_adicionar_dados_cadastrais.php, tudo certo, pois compoe o mesmo form, mas tab_adicionar_tabela_negociacao, faz parte de outro form.
Eu queria manter neste layout

Comment: então, é o que te falei no comentário anterior, vai ter que colocar a div class="tab-content  com largura e altura do form2. Coloque o form2 em uma div id="form2" fora do form1. Com css posicione a div com id=form2 em cima da div class="tab-content. Foi o que fiz na minha maquete. Veja lá no código fonte.

Comment: Talvez mudando sua pergunta para como posicionar com css uma div que contém um form dentro de uma div na pagina ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Além de não funcionar, tornará seu HTML inválido. Veja na descrição da tag [form do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

> Permitted: [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), **but with no contained <form> elements.**

Podes utilizar, também, o [validador da W3C](https://validator.w3.org/)

Mesmo assim, caso você adicionar um formulário dentro do outro, os actions de submit (seja `button` ou `input`) submeterão o `form` mais externo (o pai de todos) enviando todos os inputs, mesmo que esteja em um `form` interno.

Comment: o dow foi devido a resposta abordar o mesmo que os comentários.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo comentários não são respostas. Evite comentar votos, apenas comentários construtivos, conforme as regras do SO.

Comment: @GabrielHeming a primeira parte está correto, uma pergunta precisa ter uma resposta. Idealmente deveria ter sido postada por alguém que solucionou nos comentários. Mas comentar sobre o motivo do voto é algo bom, se a pessoa quiser. Desta forma nós sabemos que foi um voto errado, afinal parece que a resposta está certa e isto é que conta. Quem sabe o Leo repensa o voto.

Comment: @bigown obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Me expressei de forma equivocada.

Comment: pois então, a resposta foi dada após aqueles comentários afirmando não ser possível inclusive com exemplo online e o Gabriel poderia também colocar essa resposta  nos comentários a exemplo do Anderson. Mas refletindo o comentário do @bigown acho que este tem razão e vou reconsiderar, afinal eu e Anderson tivemos chance de responder antes e se não o fizemos tenho que lhe dar os devidos créditos