# Como funcionam os operadoras lógicos no PHP e como adicionar um método GET e POST diferenciando?

Tags: php

Antes de fazer essa pergunta pesquisei muito, mas não consegui resolver sozinho.
Bom eu sou novo no PHP e também na programação, queria entender como funcionam os operadores IF e ELSE no PHP e também os métodos GET e POST, o que preciso é fazer esse código funcionar mas já tentei de tudo e da um Erro:500 (Creio que é pelo código incorreto). Preciso de duas funções que não consigo implementar, uma é a função de que se alguém tentar salvar no meu arquivo bots.txt um texto vazio ou espaços aprensente um erro; A outra é que o meu botão reiniciar não funciona.

> Testei a função de reiniciar em um arquivo separado e funcionou, mas ao juntar da erro.

Exemplo: [Site](http://addbot.erkonow.com:10)

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['text'])){
    $fp = fopen("C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/COUP_Server4Edit/bots.txt" , "r");    
    $lines = '';
        while(!feof($fp)){
           $lines .= fgets($fp , 4096) ;               
        }       
    fclose($fp);
    $re = fopen("C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/COUP_Server4Edit/bots.txt" , 'w');  
    $lines .= $_POST['text'];       
    $write = fwrite($re , $lines . PHP_EOL);  
    if(empty($write) OR !strstr($write,''))
{
    echo "<script> alert('Não é permitido nomes em branco ou vazios!') </script>"; 
}
    else if($write){
        echo "<script> alert('Bot salvo com sucesso!') </script>";
  }else if($write == false ){
      echo "<script> alert('Ops.. ocorreu um erro inesperado :(')</script>";
  }
}
 if (!empty($_GET['rr'])) {
      echo "<script> alert('Servidor reiniciado com sucesso!') </script>";
exec('wscript "C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/COUP_Server4Edit/A_Fechar_Servidor_Hidden.vbs"');
  } else {
      "<script> alert('Erro ao tentar reiniciar!') </script>";
  }

echo '<form action="#" method="post">';
echo '<fieldset>'; 
echo '<legend>Erko Now | COUP - BR</legend>';
echo '<center>';
echo '<img src="img/coupbr.jpg" alt="Coup BR"><br>';
echo '<b>';
echo 'Nome do Bot:'; 
echo '</b>';
echo '<input type="text" name="text" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="Nome" title="Digite o nome do bot que deseja adicionar">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Salvar" title="Gravar informações">';
echo '<form action="#" method="get">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="rr" value="run">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Reiniciar">';
echo '</form>'; 
echo '</fieldset>'; 
echo '</center>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

**Segue abaixo o código bem identado**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['text'])){

    $fp = fopen("C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/COUP_Server4Edit/bots.txt" , "r");    
    $lines = '';
        while(!feof($fp)){
           $lines .= fgets($fp , 4096) ;               
        }       
    fclose($fp);
    $re = fopen("C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/COUP_Server4Edit/bots.txt" , 'w');  
    $lines .= $_POST['text'];       
    $write = fwrite($re , $lines . PHP_EOL);       

    if(empty($write) OR !strstr($write,'')){
        echo "<script> alert('Não é permitido nomes em branco ou vazios!') </script>"; 
    }else if($write){
            echo "<script> alert('Bot salvo com sucesso!') </script>";
    }else if($write == false ){
          echo "<script> alert('Ops.. ocorreu um erro inesperado :(')</script>";
    }

}

if (!empty($_GET['rr'])) {
    echo "<script> alert('Servidor reiniciado com sucesso!') </script>";
exec('wscript "C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/COUP_Server4Edit/A_Fechar_Servidor_Hidden.vbs"');
} else {
    "<script> alert('Erro ao tentar reiniciar!') </script>";
}

echo '<form action="#" method="post">';
echo '<fieldset>'; 
echo '<legend>Erko Now | COUP - BR</legend>';
echo '<center>';
echo '<img src="img/coupbr.jpg" alt="Coup BR"><br>';
echo '<b>';
echo 'Nome do Bot:'; 
echo '</b>';
echo '<input type="text" name="text" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="Nome" title="Digite o nome do bot que deseja adicionar">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Salvar" title="Gravar informações">';
echo '<form action="#" method="get">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="rr" value="run">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Reiniciar">';
echo '</form>'; 
echo '</fieldset>'; 
echo '</center>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Não tem problema se me passarem fontes na qual eu possa resolver meu problema, eu pesquiso por conta própria se for o caso, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Esse problema pode ser encontrado com mais facilidade com o código bem identado, fica a dica

Comment: Esse caminhos **"C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/.."** não funcionarão se seu site estiver em uma hospedagem. E dependendo da configuração do servidor ele encaminha direto para erro 500, 404, e oculta os erros do php, mysql, etc..

Comment: concordo com @AndreiCoelho pois seu site não deve possuir permissão para acessar o diretorio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código tem vários problemas!

1. Um form dentro do outro não funciona corretamente. Tem que colocar um fora do outro ou tentar conforme  [resposta desse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/form-dentro-de-um-form-html/144151#144151)
2. Essas condicionais

   ```
   if(!empty($_POST['text'])){ 
    ..........
    ..........
        if(empty($write) OR !strstr($write,'')){
   ```

   parecem não fazer sentido uma vez que `$_POST['text']` já foi verificado que não é vazio e logicamente a variável `$write` não será vazia.

   Eu usaria

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['text'])){
   .................
   .................
   $write = trim($_POST['text']); 

   if(empty($write)){
       echo "<script> alert('Não é permitido nomes em branco ou vazios!') </script>";
   ```
3. nessa linha `"<script> alert('Erro ao tentar reiniciar!') </script>";` falta um `echo`
4. Atente para o comentário do **Andrei Coelho**

   - Esse caminhos "C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/.." não funcionarão se seu site estiver em uma hospedagem. E dependendo da configuração do servidor ele encaminha direto para erro 500, 404, e oculta os erros do php, mysql, etc.

Comment: Exato. As vezes a galera não faz a configuração devida e simplemente faz um deploy pensando que o código vai funcionar em produção igual ao funcionamento local. O certo seria ele criar uma constante e usa-la no caminho absoluto dos seus arquivos.